# How to get an unknown named child in firebase on android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, parent-child

I have a root `users` node, and in that 2 device specific keys, which both refers to one-one device. I use theese keys (they are the output of the `Build.SERIAL`) to identify the 2 devices. I can retrive my device's key easily, because I know what it is. But how can I retrive the other child of the `users` node, when I don't know anything about it, because it will be created runtime? I found a solution for this, by using a `for` loop, and downloading all children of the `users` node, passing them to an `ArrayList`, then removing my device's key from the array, so only the other one remains, but I cannot use loops, because they will corrupt other parts of my app. Here is a code part:

```
private ArrayList<String> getUser = new ArrayList<>();
private ValueEventListener = mValueEventListener;
private String key = Build.SERIAL;

private void attachReadListener(){
if (mValueEventListener == null) {
        mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //getting SERIAL uploaded by partner
                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String children = childDataSnapshot.getKey();
                    getUser.add(children);
                    getUser.remove(key);
                }


                CheckOnline parseName = dataSnapshot.child(getUser.get(0)).getValue(CheckOnline.class);
//other code
```

The `CheckOnline` class is the model for getting the values inside the users/key node.

EDIT: here is my data structure:

[image]

And I cant use for loops like the one in my code, because I must have an image displayed on top of every other view, when the user touches the screen (positions, and a boolean when a finger is on the screen are passed inside the touches children, but i think they are unnecessary for this question). But because there is a loop in my code, the image, that should be on the top of my view, goes into background. (I found this out, by removing lines from this code, and when I removed the loop everthing worked fine regarding the image)

Comment: Can you add your database structure?

Comment: "I cannot use loops, because they will corrupt other parts of my app" Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Added all necessary information

Comment: A loop will not cause a view to go into the background on its own. You've done something incorrect *inside* that loop.

Comment: You can see the loop in the code, i'm 98% sure that its causing the weird behavior